# Convert java Date format into a string so MySQL can read that string

Tags: java, mysql

I need to convert a Date in java:
`Date date=calendar.getTime();` // yyyy-MM-dd
I want to turn it into a String "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" so i can insert it into a table in MySQL. Any ideea?

Comment: Stop using the oudated `java.util.Date` class. Move to the newer `java.time.` API

Comment: You better not use `Date` and `Calendar` anymore, use `java.time`, maybe `String insertMe = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: There are many examples in the internet and on stack overflow. Try to search before wirting a new question

Comment: Why do you need a `String`? What is the datatype of the column in your database?  If it is anything related to dates/times/timestamps leave it as is and let JDBC do the proper thing.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a Date object to a String in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", you can use the SimpleDateFormat class in Java.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateToStringExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = calendar.getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);

        System.out.println("Formatted Date String: " + dateString);
    }
}
```

I made an example for you, you first obtain the current date and time using the Calendar class. Then, you create an instance of SimpleDateFormat and specify the desired format pattern as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". Finally, you format the Date object using the format() method of SimpleDateFormat, which returns the formatted date string.

You can then use the dateString variable to insert the formatted date into a MySQL table

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat:

```
 Date date = new Date();
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

or

```
Date date = new Date();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(date.toInstant());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

The quickest way would be to use a *String* format using the *tF* and *tT* specifiers.
The *Formatter* class offers the complete list of specifiers.
*[Formatter (Java SE 20 & JDK 20) – Date/Time Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dt)*.

As a note, the *1$* here is to de-reference the first argument—as opposed to adding the argument twice.

```java
String string = "%tF %1$tT".formatted(date.getTime());
```

Output

```
2023-06-15 12:18:49
```

Additionally, as others have recommended, you can use the *[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)* class.

Again, the complete list of format specifiers can be found within the JavaDoc, linked above.

```java
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String string = format.format(date);
```